# iOS WKWebView how to call native function from javascript and get result in a synchronized way

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, webkit

I need to implement an API in javascript to return a value, say

```
getValue()
```

The value is passed from iOS native function in WKWebView. I can use messageHandlers to pass value but I can not change the getValue function and the messageHandler is an async call so when others call getValue() I have to return the correct value. Is there any way to achieve it ?

It seems like impossible to do in my research but Cordova is able to handle it ?

Comment: have you find anything? i also want to remove uiwebview and use WKWebview as it is for jsContext method call